# How to remove moment-locale from main bundle

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, momentjs

I am using `webpack-analyzer` to check the main bundle size and what are in that. As I can see there is `moment` which is included in `main bundle`, and there is `locale` also included in the bundle unnecessarily. I am using `moment/locale/fr` , but all the other locale is also part of it. How can I remove all the non-required packages from `moment.js`

I tried this `tsconfig.json`

```
"compilerOptions": { 
   "paths": {
      "moment": [
        "./node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js",
        "./node_modules/moment/locale/fr.js",
      ]
    }
}
```

I am also using `moment-timezone.`

But when I am doing `ng build --prod` I am getting an error:

```
This module can only be referenced with ECMAScript imports/exports by turning on the 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' flag and referencing its default export.

5 import * as moment from 'moment-timezone';
```